# Link External File LibreOffice

Tags: csv, libreoffice

I Have an Excel of my customer, and I have to link a column to another File.
In my column I can see

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,'file://myfile.xlsx'#$Foglio1.$A$2:$E$65,3,)
```

with right Path, but if I change myfile.xlsx, my data doesn't changed.

When I do a Csv, my column doesn0t have the value of myfile.xlsx

Comment: Here is the document on how to edit the link https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Edit_Links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to update the cell:

- Edit -> Links, click the Update button.

Or:

1. Close the file and reopen it.
2. It should ask, "This file contains links to other files.
   Should they be updated?"  Click Yes.

Or:

1. Open both files.
2. Select the cell containing the `VLOOKUP` statement and press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F9</kbd>

After the cell is updated, make the CSV file.